# Code Metrics Marks

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is it okay to ask a question that if my code metrics marks are good enough or not ?

I have got a picture of it and some numbers but i am not sure how to read them.

I asked question on CodeReview, but seems like they are after code not reports.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32479/is-this-code-metrics-results-good

In short is this question eligible for SO ?

Comment: Sounds opinion based, but do you have an example question

Comment: Nope, it has marks, like class coupling, depth of inheritance etc..

Comment: @user13814 The metrics aren't subjective, but the question or whether those metrics are good or bad *is* subjective.

Comment: why negative vote, its a simple question... my days

Comment: Negative vote wasn't from me, but perhaps because without an example question this is difficult to answer

Comment: @RichardTingle Just for you i added a example question :)

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. Seems to have allowed Servy to answer the question; success!

Comment: @user13814 Such a question is certainly not appropriate on code review.  You have shown no code to review.

Comment: @Servy oh okay, I deleted it, thanks for telling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A question asking if they are good or bad would be too subjective for the site.

If you don't know what the metric is measuring or even what the term means, then there's *potential* for a question there.

Having said that, wanting to know what cyclomatic complexity means, or what coupling is, etc. are all things that you should be spending time researching before coming here.  You should be looking up their definitions, searching the web for information about what they mean, how measuring it can be useful, etc.  I would be very surprised that simply asking what such a term means, for anything on that metric, would be something you couldn't find the answer to with a few google searches.  If, however, you do your research and are not able to find information on the subject the such a question may be on topic on programmers.stackexchange.com.  Keep in mind that when asking such a question you should *demonstrate* that you've done research; show what you did find about it, and what you still don't understand after looking through those resources.

Note that if you did end up asking such a question there would be no need for you to show what your values of that metric were.  The question would only be to help you understand what the metric means in general, not whether your code has a "good" or "bad" value for that metric.

Comment: I did some research before coming here, and find this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385914.aspx, I read definitions and tried to match them with result I got but it seems like a political statements on MSDN then actually telling me whats right or wrong, they are giving green for 20 - 100 , which makes no sense to me @ MaintainbilityIndex, hence wanted to ask experience programmers about it to be honest

Comment: @user13814 As I said, asking for people's *opinions* on whether your values are good or not is not an appropriate question for the site.  Questions on the site should be objective, and be able to have a verifyably correct answer.